# Solving recurrences using substitution method

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

So I'm currently taking Algorithms course and I'm having an issue solving recurrences and obtaining the running time. I was wondering if someone could explain it to me in layman terms how to solve using substitution method.

Question from the book: 
Algorithm B solves problems of size n by recursively solving two subproblems of size n − 1
and then combining the solutions in constant time.

Which led me to coming up with the following recurrence: `T(n)=2T(n-1)+O(1)`. I then came up with `O(1)=1`. Which gave me the following: `T(n)=2T(n-1)+1`

Here's my attempt at solving it

```
T(n)=2T(n-1)+1
=2(2T(n-2)+1)+1=4T(n-2)+3
=4(2T(n-3)+1)+3=8T(n-3)+7
=8(2T(n-4)+1)+7=16T(n-4)+15
=16(2T(n-5)+1)+15=32T(n-5)+31
=32T(2T(n-6)+1)+31=64T(n-6)+63
```

If I'm doing it right, how do I continue to get the running time? Can someone explain in layman terms how to use the substitution method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but you can format your back substitution so it makes a bit more sense:

```
T(n)
=2^1T(n-1)+(2^1-1)
=2^2T(n-2)+(2^2-1)
=2^3T(n-3)+(2^3-1)
=2^4T(n-4)+(2^4-1)
=2^5T(n-5)+(2^5-1)
=2^6T(n-6)+(2^6-1)
...
```

You can see a pattern here as `n` approaches `0`. It becomes something like `2^n + 2^n - 1`, and in Big-O notation, `O(2^n)`.

Some insight that I had that might help you with other recurrence relations: the recurrence happens `n` times and each iteration multiplies by 2. Sounds something like `2^n`!

Comment: Thank you! So I was on the correct track. I noticed that it was doubling each step so I thought the Big-O was O(2^n).

I have another question if you don't mind me asking, when do you use the master theorem vs the substitution method?

Comment: You can only use the master theorem for recurrence relations of a specific form, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem. Personally, I see if the recurrence relation can be even solved using the master theorem. If it's not of the right form, I use the substitution method.